# Failed Create Space Time Cube from Multidimensional Raster tool

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, space-time-cube

I am creating a space-time cube from global forest watch forest loss data. I have created a multidimensional raster of years from 2001-2020 of forest loss cells. I run the Create Space Time Cube from Multidimensional Raster tool in ArcGIS Pro 2.7.3. I ran from the geoprocessing pane, I used the default settings with view to adjust after the first successful run. I used an multidimensional raster in .crf format meeting the conditions required including 10 time steps. The tool fails and I got this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4594, in execute
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSCube.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.__initialize(cubeObj)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSCube.py", line 168, in __initialize
    self.__createDimensions(cubeObj)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSCube.py", line 540, in __createDimensions
    self.__createLocationVariable(lat, 'latitude', latValues)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSCube.py", line 626, in __createLocationVariable
    var[:] = value
  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 4992, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__setitem__
  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 5271, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable._put
  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 1928, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error
 Failed to execute (CreateSpaceTimeCubeMDRasterLayer).
```

What is causing the tool to fail and how can I fix it?

Comment: What parameter values did you use with the tool? I'm assuming you ran it from the Geoprocessing pane.

Comment: Yes I ran from the geoprocessing pane, I used the default settings with view to adjust after the first successful run. I used an multidimensional raster in .crf format

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Can you edit your question to confirm your .crf (Cloud Raster Format) meets the requirements as specified in the [help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/space-time-pattern-mining/createcubefrommdrasterlayer.htm), i.e must have at least 10 time intervals, the number of raster cells x the number of time intervals is less than two billion.

Comment: I'm not sure of what caused the fix but instead of saving to my onedrive I saved to my desktop and the tool ran.